# MVC5 Scaffolding, Data Context Class Dropdown Empty

Tags: .net, entity-framework-6, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

Framework .NET 4.5.1, MVC5, EntityFramework 6.1.3

I'm trying to add a new scaffolding item, and when i do, the dropdown is empty except for a single model that i happen to create before i upgraded from MVC4 to MVC5.

I've seen a few other topics on this, and most people say you just have to rebuild it. I've rebuilt and created new models and none of them i can get to show up in the Data Context Class dropdown menu.